# skin folder path wrong

Tags: magento-1.7, base-url, skin

I've cloned locally a copy of a website, changed the base url and it loads fine but the skin folder path is not correct:
http://local.web.com/Volumes/MacCs/htdocs/website/httpdocs/skin/frontend/default/theme/css/datepicker.css

it should be instead: http://local.web.com/skin/frontend/default/theme/css/datepicker.css

I checked anywhere in config_core_data, disabled htaccess, double checked the MAMP PRO host configuration, cache disabled. 
Any idea what is wrong?
thanks

Comment: did you check the file owner and permissions?

Comment: did you clear cache?

Comment: yes, cache disabled

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple issues here. Looking at the way your URL looks, it could be the permissions of the files and folders. For more info about that please take a look at the [Magento 1 DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html). The other problem could be that the path to the skin folder is set incorrectly or your VirtualHost is setup incorrectly. Both these issues don't seem to be the case here, if you ask me, since you could open the homepage, so the VirtualHost is correct, and you made a 1-on-1 copy from the live environment, so if the paths are incorrect here, they should be incorrect on live as well.

So if your paths to the skin folder, the media folder or JavaScript files are incorrect, please check the [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html).